# Details of "association bonus" don't match descriptions

Tags: discussion, association-bonus, association

I just noticed [a newcomer in Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21461/martine-votvik?tab=reputation) that had a +100 association bonus listed a week after joining.  Huh?  It appears that he joined *another* SE and maybe got a bonus *here* since he hadn't initially (being his first SE)?

From the question flagged as a duplicate (similar wording to what I've seen):

> The bonus is awarded because you have proven that you know your way around the basic features of any Stack Exchange website, and with those 100 extra points you can now comment, vote, flag and create bounties on all SE sites

But, that would be contrary to the meaning in two different ways. The meaning is to get over a first hump of privilege if you're experienced already. Joining a different SE does not provde any experience.  And, he's already over that hump, a week after signing up.

The answer given below explains everything, but contradicts all the documentation and previous explaination on what this is for.

Comment: Well, I can read the message it gives me when I get one, the pop-up, etc. so I would have thought that I knew how it works.  It sounds like this is "already known", and contradictory to what it states.

Answer (score 3):

The association bonus is designed to encourage participation on multiple sites. Therefore, it is contrary to its design goals to give a bonus to someone with only one site account just for crossing 200.

It would also make no sense at all to exclude any particular account from the +100 bonus given to all sites, so the bonus just lands on all of them.

In other words, the bonus is not really "You are definitely a trustworthy user, fully meriting this 100 rep everywhere you go"; it's more "Go places and see sites, and you probably can't do *too* much harm with a measly 100 extra at the bottom of the scale".